# List the names of folders horizontally with a loop

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I need to list the names of folders horizontally.

```vb
Sub 2()
    Dim objFSO As Object
    Dim objFolder As Object
    Dim objSubFolder As Object
    Dim i As Integer
    
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder("C:\Users\Betty\AppData\Roaming\MetaQuotes\Terminal\B4D9BCD10BE9B5248AFCB2BE2411BA10\MQL4\Files\Export_History")
    i = 1

    For Each objSubFolder In objFolder.subfolders
        Cells(1, i + 1) = objSubFolder.Name
    Next objSubFolder

End Sub
```

I get this result:
[image: Code Output]

Stepping into the code with the debugger, I see that it overwrites each file name in the same cell.

Comment: You've set variable i outside your for loop, then just add 1 for each iteration.  The result is 2 for each iteration.  Suggest to set i to zero then inside the for say i=i+1, and remove the +1 from Cells.

btw, I really like your backward R

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to increment i inside the loop to avoid overwriting

```
For Each objSubFolder In objFolder.subfolders
    Cells(1, i + 1) = objSubFolder.Name
    i = i + 1
Next objSubFolder
```

This might be simpler to start i at 2 and remove the initial + 1 as I suspect you actually want to go one cell at a time

```
i = 2

For Each objSubFolder In objFolder.subfolders
    Cells(1, i ) = objSubFolder.Name
    i = i + 1
Next objSubFolder
```

Comment: Obviously a rookie mistake. Thank you. Will mark it as an answer in 10 minutes.

Comment: thank you. Probably worth mentioning you should reference the sheet explicitly and not just the ActiveSheet implicitly with Cells as you might hit problems if you are not in the expected sheet.

Comment: Thanks for the advise. I am running each chunk of code to a separate workbook, because the whole code of the general file is quite long. I will reference the sheet when I transfer this chunk to the general code.

Comment: Thanks! By the way... I have another issue and I wondered if you could take a look at it  - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48940448/proper-loop-trough-sub-folders-in-a-directory-and-import-of-specified-columns-fr .